# Ubuntu Apache2 DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot

Tags: server, apache2, directory

I have a web server running Ubuntu 17.04 that I am attempting to set up with `Apache`. Everything ran great until I decided to host two websites on a single machine through virtualHosts. Now `apache` refuses to start up with even a single host enabled. Each time I attempt to start `Apache` I get this error:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot.
```

None of my attempts to fix this have come to anything including:

```
apt purge apache2 && rm -r /etc/apache2
```

All line 80 of the error message tells me is `DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}`.

And at no time do I see where or what `APACHE_RUN_DIR` is declared as.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 50):

The command

```
source /etc/apache2/envvars
```

sorted my problem out (after trying ALL the others).

To check whether all is well or not use the command

```
apache2 -S
```

I found that was quicker than using my DNS records.

Comment: I used the `source /etc/apache2/envvars` but after that my home directory changed from `~` to `home` and when I wrote cd it showed `-bash: cd: HOME not set`. When I entered the envvars one of the first lines is `# this won't be correct after changing uid` and `unset HOME`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I used to run `apache2 --version` to see if any error occurs.

Answer (score 19):

There is a missing update in "man apache2", at least for option -V;

Today, one should use either "apachectl" or "apache2ctl" instead of

"apache2" for at least some options, as stated in

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=879571

Comment: It is not at all clear how this answers the question.

Comment: This is the key information because everything worked for the user. Users should not use `apache2` but `apache2ctl` and this is written in the main apache configuration file.

Comment: @RandyCragun This answer helped me because running `apachectl` actually showed the error not on line 80 of `apache2.conf`, but in my config file for the site. It actually showed that the error was an unknown directive because of `mod_rewrite` not being enabled.

Answer (score 7):

Apache2 uses `/etc/apache2/envvars` to set environment variables. You can use this information to make sure the directory `${APACHE_RUN_DIR}` points to is valid.

I was experiencing the same issue while upgrading from 14.04 to 17.04.
Problem was: `${APACHE_RUN_DIR}` was set to `/var/run/apache2`, but the apache2 folder was missing in `/var/run`.

The fix for me was: `mkdir /var/run/apache2`

Comment: even if you created the folder or if the folder is already presented (like in my situation) you have to have to run the following command.
`source /etc/apache2/envvars`

Comment: you only need to run the envvares command if you are starting Apache without the startscript, if you are using init.d/system.d the file will be sourced automatically.

Comment: @Peshmerge THanks! can you tell me how to retain it after reboot? it seems on reboot we have to manually execute that command everytime

Comment: Works with docker :)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, and could solve it by using:

```
apache2ctl start
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case it was regarding "Require all denied" line in apache2.conf file which (again) in my case was typed in as just "Require denied"

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Ubuntu 20.14 and Apache2 after running Vagrant. My resolution was to change the Document Root in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Before Change -> `DocumentRoot /var/www/HTML`

I deleted the "HTML" (because I am not using the HTML directory (this is just for development no production)

After Change -> `DocumentRoot /var/www/`

I then restarted Apache

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2
sudo systemctl start apache2
```

and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Reenebling `php5.6` apache module helps to fix this problem.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type these:

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6
sudo a2enmod php5.6
```

Then restart apache2 service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this error and run through all the ideas given and none worked. What I had done was changed the URL in the `sites-available` `.conf` file, restarted apache and boom. It stopped working. The solution is to go into `sites-enabled` and remove the old file there and then restart apache2. I hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of which I found;

**apache2 -S** replied;

**apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
DefaultRuntimeDir takes one argument, Common directory for run-time files (shared memory, locks, etc.)**

Line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
**DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}**

Line 86 gave away the /etc/apache2/envars file which shows this:

**export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX/apache2.pid**

**export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2$SUFFIX**

**export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX**

Indicating the environment is set.

Looking at the /var/run/apache2 folder, it is owned by Root.

Run: **chown -R www-data:www-data /var/run/apache2**

Which should now allow the non-root user running Apache2 to write to the folder
Re-run **systemctl restart apache2**

**apache2 -S** Now works properly.